# How can I handle Overrun and Framing errors in UART transmissions on PIC16 devices?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, uart, communication, interrupts

I am transmitting and receiving data over UART between two PIC16 devices using interrupts, but at random times, one of them seems to block its receiver and it stays stuck in that position permanently. If I clear the INTCON.GIE bit at every received byte and then set it to 1 after I've finished processing the data in the ISR, it does not get stuck anymore, but I am getting stack underflow errors which force the device to reset. I am guessing this is because of some sort of framing errors, how can I prevent this?

Comment: I'm afraid that you need to debug your code. You might want to show it here, as a reproducible complete minimal example. You can start by "exporting" status bits of the receiving UART to port pins and watch them by an oscilloscope or logic analyzer. Read the PIC's documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

With PIC16F controllers when the UART receive overrun is asserted the receive interrupt request cannot be cleared until the UART receive overrun condition has been resolved.

Most of the PIC16F data sheets describe how this should be done.

For the PIC16F18877 this method is described in section:

> 33.1.2.5 Receive Overrun Error
>
> The receive FIFO buffer can hold two characters. An overrun error will
> be generated if a third character, in its entirety, is received before
> the FIFO is accessed. When this happens the OERR bit of the RC1STA
> register is set. The characters already in the FIFO buffer can be read
> but no additional characters will be received until the error is
> cleared. The error must be cleared by either clearing the CREN bit of
> the RC1STA register or by resetting the EUSART by clearing the SPEN
> bit of the RC1STA register.

Depending on the specific controller you are using the method may be different.

Comment: Are you using any delays in your code?

Comment: @Gil, Your comment does not make sense. No code has been posted in this topic. Using delays is never a good choice in an interrupt handler and usually a cause of problems anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting stack underflow errors which force the device to reset

That's likely caused by incorrect actions by the interrupt handler. Make sure that the interrupt handler routine is declared as an interrupt handler in C, and if you code it in assembly, ensure that you're using correct entry and exit code.